# CSipSimple where is the sip_home.xml file?

Tags: android, csip-simple

In a quest to understand CSipSimple opensource app, I checked it out and compiled it successfully. However -> in the file SipHome.java of package com.csipsimple.ui, inside the onCreate() method:

setContentView(R.layout.sip_home);

The question is : where can I find sip_home.xml file ? I only found two files :

1 - sip_home_one_pane.xml
2 - sip_home_dual_pane.xml

No sip_home.xml : what is going on ? how does the application decide how to load R.layout.sip_home ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in [layout.xml](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/res/values/layout.xml?spec=svn1659&r=1659) in res/values folder. It is defined a layout reference to @layout/sip_home_one_pane.

https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/res/values/layout.xml?spec=svn1659&r=1659